# Day of the week dd/mm/yyyy format in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr, format

I need to change my date column format in R to show the output as ddd dd/mm/yyyy like Ms Excel can do.

I have the following dates:

```
dates <- as.Date(
  c(
  "2022-03-30",
  "2022-03-31",
  "2022-04-08",
  "2022-04-12"
 ) 
)
```

How did can I change the dates format for ddd dd-mm-yyyy like Ms Excel in R using dplyr inside mutate function ?

Comment: A possible solution: `dates %>% format("%d/%m/%Y")`.

Comment: I need something like Wed 30/03/2022 ....

Comment: The following does that, @RodrigoH.Ozon: `dates %>% format("%a %d/%m/%Y")`.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting the vector `dates` can be done using `format`. The short weekday can be extracted using %a, full weekday name is %A.

```r
dates <- as.Date(
  c(
  "2022-03-30",
  "2022-03-31",
  "2022-04-08",
  "2022-04-12"
 ) 
)
cat(format(dates, "%a %d/%m/%Y"), sep="\n")
```

To use within dplyr::mutate

```r
data.frame(dates) %>% 
    mutate(dates_formatted = format(dates,"%a %d/%m/%Y"))
```